# Fast algorithm for Polar Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, approximation

As it known, according to the Polar Decomposition, square matrix can be expressed in the next form $$M=QR$$ ($Q$ - orthogonal matrix $R$ - positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrix)

I need to find this $Q$ factor for the case of $3\times 3$ matrix. For this purpose I use next well known iterative formula

$$
Q_{i+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left[ Q_i+(Q_i^{-1})^T \right]
$$

where the $\det Q_0\neq0 $
However, on practice it works a little bit slowly (it takes, more than 15 iteration before finds right answer). Is there any other, faster algorithms exist to perform Polar Decomposition? I have found exact formula for finding $Q$ factor for the case of $2\times 2$ matrices.

$$Q = M + \mathrm{sign}(\det M)\begin{pmatrix}
  d & -c\\
  -b & a\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
where the initial matrix $$M=\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b\\
  c & d\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
 Does such formula exist for $3\times 3$ matrix?

Comment: Maybe this question is a bit obvious, but just to be thorough: have you tried the LAPACK QR routine?

Comment: It's not the QR decomposition, the original poster just used the same letters. In the polar decomposition, the $R$ is positive semidefinite and not triangular.

Comment: A faster iteration than the one you are using is described in: Yuji Nakatsukasa and Nicholas J. Higham, Backward stability of iterations for computing the polar decomposition, SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications, Vol. 33, No. 2, pp. 460-479, 2012. However, I am not sure if this is the best way if you are only working with $3\times 3$ matrices; if you find a (stable) closed form as suggested below it is probably much faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the problem to computing the [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), for which there exist many fast methods and codes. For fast 3x3 SVD, I found [this paper](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~sifakis/papers/SVD_TR1690.pdf).

To reduce the polar decomposition to the SVD, suppose the polar decomposition is written in the following form, 
$$M = U P,$$

with orthogonal $U$ and positive semidefinite $P$ (Ie., $Q \rightarrow U$, $R \rightarrow P$ from your notation). Further, denote the SVD of $P$ by
$$P = V \Sigma V^T.$$

Substituting the second equation into the first yields, 
$$M = U V \Sigma V^T.$$

In other words, if you compute the SVD of $M$,
$$M = W \Sigma V^T,$$

then $P$ is given by the above formula, and 
$$U = W V^T.$$

---

Incidentally, when you want to prove the existence of SVD-like decompositions for infinite dimensional operators, one basic strategy is to start with the polar decomposition which is easier to prove, and then do these steps backwards.

Comment: I think you need to use the conjugate transpose instead of the regular transpose.

Comment: Sure, if your input matrix is complex-valued then you need the conjugate transpose. However, if it is real valued then $V$ is real-valued so it doesn't matter. (unlike the eigenvalue decomposition where real matrices could have complex eigenvectors)

Answer (score 1):

Section 2.5 in [Continuum Mechanics by A.J.M. Spencer](http://books.google.com/books?id=AJdfQL0rgrgC&printsec=frontcover) is devoted to the 3x3 polar decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

A more recent publication has come out with a new method for solving the 3x3 polar decomposition.

[An algorithm to compute the polar decomposition of a 3x3 matrix](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/2352/01/covered/MIMS_ep2015_66.pdf)

(I'm really surprised OP was needing 15 iterations for the iterative method!)